# Intellij Idea's Completion Style for Bash

Tags: bash, intellij-idea

Is there any smarter bash completion than the normal one. I'm imagining having something like the auto completion feature of Intellij Idea. For example is there is a folder named **anExampleFolder**, if I type **aEF** or even **aef** and then press tab it completes it or somehow open a drop down menu.

Comment: What is the normal one? The Bash plugin? That is it.

Comment: By normal one I meant the one and comes with a ubuntu installation. I just searches in strings that the typed string is a prefix for.

Comment: Could you send me a link to it? Thanks.

Comment: Ah if only such a thing existed. I was just looking for the same thing and found this through Google :(

Comment: Actually... this may be of interest: http://www.debian-administration.org/article/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2  - it does at least give some hope for implementing it...

Answer (score 2):

[fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) ("fuzzy finder for your shell") may be what you're looking for.  For your example of cd-ing to anExampleFolder, you have 3 options using fzf:

- fd<kbd>RET</kbd>aEF<kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

  - Launch `fzf` with recursive list of child directories.  Enter fuzzy search term `aEF`, select match with arrow keys, accept.
- <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>aEF<kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

  - Same as above but using a key binding instead of shell function
- cd aEF**<kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

  - Using the experimental auto-completion integration

Note that in all cases the arrow keys may not be necessary, if the fuzzy-search finds what you're looking for as the first match.  And it can be used for lots of other stuff besides `cd`; the GitHub [README](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/README.md) has plenty of other examples and bindings.

Answer (score 0):

As sylvanaar said - [Bash plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=4230) for Intellij should be enough.

Comment: Oh. There is a miss understanding going on here. Basically I want a plugin for BASH not Intellij!

Answer (score 0):

zsh has such intelligent autocompletion mechanisms as plugins.
In combination with [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) and the plugin [fasd](https://github.com/clvv/fasd) you should achieve even more than what IntelliJ offers.

Comment: ...though with zsh implementing better-designed expansion rules than the POSIX ones, it's very easy to get into habits there that result in serious (sometimes even security-impacting) bugs when writing code for POSIX-compliant shells. I have trouble advising `zsh` for use by folks who may be writing code for bash, ksh, or any other shell following POSIX rules.

Comment: I have to say I can't agree. In the terminal, I'm using zsh all the time with lots of plugins and extra features, while on the other hand I develop a massive scripted system specifically in bash. I have no problem separating one from the other. It's just like speaking two similar languages. Any examples of security risks mentioned?

Comment: With respect to security -- the big issue is quoting expansions. Being able to put, say, `/ /etc/passwd /` in the middle of a file's path and have that be expanded when someone wasn't careful to quote is a risk. Likewise for glob characters and such. I've actually seen multiple TB of backups purged by a poorly-written script on account of just such a bug (when a buffer overflow wrote garbage into a filename), so it's not purely theoretical.